# How to add logging in Geb

Tags: groovy, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, geb

I am using Geb with Gradle/Groovy/Selenium Cucumber.

How can I do logging to the console while run via terminal. Further even though I can use `println` statement in groovy code those not get printed in the console.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to see standard streams (i.e. standard out to which `println()` writes) printed to the console when running tests via gradle build then you need to enable it for your `test` task:

```
test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

You can also see standard out in one of the tabs in test reports even if you don't enable the above option.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The one you suggested works and could see the logs in console. But under the test reports `...\build\reports\tests\index.html ` cannot see logs. Just passed failed status.